# How to convert an existing customized SwapChainPanel from C++/CX to C++/WinRT

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm attempting to convert my existing C++/CX code to C++/WinRT in order to figure out whether that would enable me to compile that code using Clang. However, I'm stuck early on.

The C++/CX code that I need to convert is used to build a Direct3D component (based on `SwapChainPanel`) that is eventually utilized in a Windows UWP app that is written in C#. The problem I'm facing is that I just don't manage to convert my customized `SwapChainPanel` to C++/WinRT.

The code looks as follows:

```
namespace Why::Does::This::Not::Work
{
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public ref class BaseView : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel
  {
  protected private:
    BaseView();
    // Lots of other stuff
  };
}


namespace Why::Does::This::Not::Work
{
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public ref class CustomView sealed : public BaseView
  {
  public:
    CustomView();
    // ...

    event AnimationEventHandler^ AnimationStarted;

  private protected:
    // Lots of private protected stuff
  };
}


namespace Why::Does::This::Not::Work
{
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public ref class AnimationEventArgs sealed
  {
  public:
    AnimationEventArgs() {}

    AnimationEventArgs(int start, int end)
    {
      Start = start;
      End   = end;
    }

    property int Start;
    property int End;
  };

  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public delegate void AnimationEventHandler(Platform::Object^ sender, AnimationEventArgs^ e);
}
```

As far as I'm able to interpret the documentation I need to do what is described under [If you're authoring a runtime class to be referenced in your XAML UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis#if-youre-authoring-a-runtime-class-to-be-referenced-in-your-xaml-ui) in the documentation.

So, it seems to me that I'd need to author an IDL file in order to generate the COM stuff that is required. However, I cannot even make the skeleton IDL compile:

```
namespace Why
{
  namespace Does
  {
    namespace This
    {
      namespace Not
      {
        namespace Work
        {
          runtimeclass CustomView : Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel
          {
            CustomView();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When attempting to compile the above code all I'm getting is

```
error MIDL2025: [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting { near ":"
error MIDL2026: [msg]cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation
```

I apologize if you view this as a stupid question. I have read the corresponding documentation but I just fail to comprehend what is really going on when utilizing C++/WinRT. I have plenty of experience with C++ but zero with COM which means it is everything else than straight forward to understand C++/WinRT.

If someone can lend me a hand translating the above C++/CX code to C++/WinRT that would be highly appreciated. Please don't just point me to the documentation, that just doesn't help.

---

**EDIT:**

Modifying the sample IDL code as follows successfully compiled it:

```
namespace Why
{
  namespace Does
  {
    namespace This
    {
      namespace Not
      {
        namespace Work
        {
          [default_interface]
          runtimeclass CustomView : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel
          {
            CustomView();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, exposing a user control to another language, in my case C#, such as the one inheriting from `SwapChainPanel` is dramatically more complex than doing the same thing in C++/CX. There's an IDL to deal with that is not easy to handle because there don't seem to be any complex samples around. That IDL generates several header files that I'm not really sure about what to do with because the documentation is lacking and samples are sparse. C++/WinRT is not for the faint-hearted and its complexity compared to C++/CX is simpy much higher.

It seems to me that to *really* understand C++/WinRT it is a necessity to have a good grasp of COM because compared to C++/CX, C++/WinRT does a poor job of hiding those COM related internals. This is especially the case when dealing with DirectX. Add to this an IDL that in itself is hard to deal with and a documentation of it that might suffice to get simple samples up and running but does not help much when porting a full fledged C++/CX app.

Doing what we do with C++/CX in C++/WinRT is just not economical for and we will stay on C++/CX until C++/WinRT becomes *much* more user friendly. Eliminating the need for the IDL (see https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/36095386-get-rid-of-idl-for-c-winrt-components) would help too.

Without the prospect of being able to compile our code using Clang I would not even think about moving away from C++/CX. Microsoft shouldn't wonder that the adoption of C++/WinRT is slow. If they seriously want to change that they have to lower the entry barrier considerably.

Comment: Having written decades of COM code, I'm probably a bit biased here. However, my take is, that C++/WinRT does a *tremendous* job at hiding all the COM underpinnings. You never see any `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, or `Release` calls, neither are you exposed to the details of type activation or factory implementations. In fact, it hides COM just a bit too much: When you pass `MyType` by value, it depends on the namespace, whether you are passing an implementation type by value, or a smart pointer to the implementation type, semantically identical to pass-by-ref.

Comment: Still, C++/WinRT *is* a challenging approach to the Windows Runtime. The barrier to entry might appear **huge**, but it's really not all that bad, once you've played with it for a while. I'm now on my second C++/WinRT toy project, and it mostly feels like writing C# code, but with the flexibility and raw power of C++. My advice: Keep playing with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's helpful to get other opinions here because its hard to see what is ahead. I just have to see what I can do given the time constraints that we have.

Answer (score 2):

Fully qualified type names in IDL use the period (`.`) as the namespace separator. A working IDL file would look like this:

```
namespace Why
{
  namespace Does
  {
    namespace This
    {
      namespace Not
      {
        namespace Work
        {
          runtimeclass CustomView : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel
          {
            CustomView();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's fairly complete documentation at [Microsoft Interface Definition Language 3.0 reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/). Even with that, it's often challenging to make any sense out of MIDL error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Compiling the modified sample that you provided resulted in the MIDL compiler error `error MIDL5053: [msg]empty runtime class cannot have the [composable] or [activatable] attribute [context]: [ RuntimeClass 'Why.Does.This.Not.Work.CustomView'  ]`. Then I came across that error message in a comment you made here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845563. That led me to add the `[default_interface]` attribute above the `runtimeclass` code line which resolved the error. However, now I'm just getting the following error (see next comment)

Comment: `error MIDL2212: [msg]error while writing to file [context]SetViewTest.winmd (HRESULT:0x80070003 - The system cannot find the path specified. )`. I verified the settings associated with the .idl file and compared them to the settings used in the PhotoEditor sample app and a newly created Windows Runtime Component Visual Studio project and they match exactly. No idea what is going on here, I'm lost.

Comment: Hmm, never mind. That error message went away when I cleaned out all build output and rebuilt everything from scratch. So far so good, I'll get back to this question once I know more.